# Overthrow scrollbars not showing

Tags: html, ios, css, cordova, scrollbar

I am using **Overthrow** to safely use CSS overflow in a **cordova mobile app** for momentum scrolling.

I have an absolute positioned div with the following styles:

```
.scrollable{
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.overthrow-enabled .overthrow {
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

On **iOS** momentum scrolling works great but the scrollbar doesn't show.

I don't think it depends on Overthrow, could it be a CSS problem?
Can anyone help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem. If inside the scrollable element I place a div with a min-height lower than the scrollable element height, the scroll bar won't show (even if the overal height of the element is greater then the height of the scrollable element). This is a very strange behaviour!